# How do I change localization in my j2me program with LWUIT?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, lwuit

I've created a localization table in my project's res-file using LWUIT Resource editor. But it turns out, that I don't know how to switch through different localizations. How can I set up a global language for my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can merge two diffrent localizations to one.(the default save in bundle and merge with new localization mergeL10N(these objects are hashTable))

```
if (themeName != null && !themeName.equals(this.currThemeName)) {
            try {
                if (themeName.equals(DEFAULT_THEME_NAME)) {
                    defaultTheme = Resources.open(DEFAULT_THEME_NAME);
                    bundle = null;
                } else {
                    defaultTheme = Resources.open(DEFAULT_THEME_NAME);
                    bundle = Resources.open(themeName);
                }
               mergeL10N = defaultTheme.getL10N("Localization (L10N) 1", "iw");
                if (bundle != null) {
                  mergeHashtable(mergeL10N, bundle.getL10N("Localization (L10N) 1", "iw"));
                 }
                  UIManager.getInstance().setResourceBundle(mergeL10N);

                                      }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must open your res and use the table that you want to use, here you can find an example

```
try {
        Constants.res = Resources.open("/Lang.res");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("can't load resource file:" + e);
    }
Hashtable h = Constants.res.getL10N("English.res","en");
```